# Modifying the section style

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, chapters

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,arrows}
\newcommand\titlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=0.5cm,trim right=2.5cm] {%
    \node [
        text = red!70!green,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum height=3.5ex] (a) at (2.5cm,0.6ex) {%
    };
   \path[fill=red!70!blue] (a.east) circle (.5ex);
   \draw[color=red!70!blue, thick,rounded corners=1ex] (a.east) |- (\textwidth+3cm,-0.75ex);
}
}

\newcommand\subtitlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=1cm,trim right=3.05cm] {%
    \node[
        text = red!70!green,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum height=3.5ex] (b) at (3.05cm,0.6ex) {%
    };
   \path[fill=red!70!blue] (b.east) circle (.5ex);
   \draw[color=red!70!blue, thick,rounded corners=1ex] (b.east) |- (\textwidth+2cm,-0.75ex);
}%
}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\sf}{\subtitlebar}{0.2cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-2cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{name=\subsection,numberless}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}


\titleformat{\section}{\large\sf}{\titlebar}{0.25cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-2.15cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{name=\section,numberless}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a test}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[4-5]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

This code , generates the section styles as follows :
How do I remove the lines (the red lines). and increase the font size of the section name and change the font size

[image]

Comment: Comment out the line in the `\subtitlebar` command that reads: `\draw[color=red!70!blue, ... -0.75ex);` and add, say `\large` between `\normalfont` and `\sf` in the `\titleformat` command.  (Untested; and assumes you want to keep the red 'ball'...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `\titlebar` and `\subtitlebar` from `\titleformat` and adjust the spacings.

In the case of sections, change your current definitions from

```
\titleformat{\section}{\large\sf}{\titlebar}{0.25cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-2.15cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

to

```
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\sffamily}{}{0cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

instead of `\LARGE`, use any other of the font size switches or even `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont`.

Similar modifications will be needed for subsections.

A complete example, using your code with the modifications suggested:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,arrows}
\newcommand\titlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=0.5cm,trim right=2.5cm] {%
    \node [
        text = red!70!green,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum height=3.5ex] (a) at (2.5cm,0.6ex) {%
    };
   \path[fill=red!70!blue] (a.east) circle (.5ex);
   \draw[color=red!70!blue, thick,rounded corners=1ex] (a.east) |- (\textwidth+3cm,-0.75ex);
}
}

\newcommand\subtitlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=1cm,trim right=3.05cm] {%
    \node[
        text = red!70!green,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum height=3.5ex] (b) at (3.05cm,0.6ex) {%
    };
   \path[fill=red!70!blue] (b.east) circle (.5ex);
   \draw[color=red!70!blue, thick,rounded corners=1ex] (b.east) |- (\textwidth+2cm,-0.75ex);
}%
}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\sffamily}{}{0cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{name=\subsection,numberless}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}


\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\sffamily}{}{0cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{name=\section,numberless}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a test}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[4-5]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to remove the rule but keeping the dot, you can define a commad for the dot:

```
\newcommand\titledot{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.65ex] {%
\path[fill=red!70!blue] (0,0) circle (.5ex);
  }
}
```

and then use

```
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\sffamily}{\llap{\titledot}}{0cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

An example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,arrows}
\newcommand\titlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=0.5cm,trim right=2.5cm] {%
    \node [
        text = red!70!green,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum height=3.5ex] (a) at (2.5cm,0.6ex) {%
    };
   \path[fill=red!70!blue] (a.east) circle (.5ex);
   \draw[color=red!70!blue, thick,rounded corners=1ex] (a.east) |- (\textwidth+3cm,-0.75ex);
}
}

\newcommand\subtitlebar{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=1cm,trim right=3.05cm] {%
    \node[
        text = red!70!green,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum height=3.5ex] (b) at (3.05cm,0.6ex) {%
    };
   \path[fill=red!70!blue] (b.east) circle (.5ex);
   \draw[color=red!70!blue, thick,rounded corners=1ex] (b.east) |- (\textwidth+2cm,-0.75ex);
}%
}

\newcommand\titledot{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.65ex] {%
\path[fill=red!70!blue] (0,0) circle (.5ex);
  }
}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\sffamily}{\llap{\titledot}}{0cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{name=\subsection,numberless}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}


\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\sffamily}{\llap{\titledot}}{0cm}{\textcolor{blue!60!green}{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{name=\section,numberless}{0cm}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is a test}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[4-5]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `\sf` is a  TeX command which shouldn't be used anymore in modern LaTeX documents; use `\sffamily` instead.

Comment: How to modify the font size and style of section name?

Comment: @subhamsoni I already explained how to change the font size in my answer. What do you mean by changing the style? Do you want to use a different font? Which one?

Comment: like Verdina or Segoe UI with 36 pt

Comment: @subhamsoni Are those t1 fonts or are you using TrueType fonts and  `xelatex`? For the size, instead of `\LARGE`, use `\fontsize{36}{43}\selectfont` and make sure the fonts are scalable.

Comment: @subhamsoni assuming a t1 font like the given by [`verdana`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verdana) package, you can use `\fontfamily{vna}\fontsize{36}{43}\selectfont`. Of course, this requires the font to be installed.

Comment: Yes. I would like to use only those fonts that are installed..

Comment: @subhamsoni if the `verdana` font provided by the CTAN package I linked to before is installed, then you can use the commands I provided in my previous comment.